# ubuntu for raspberry piのカーネルを変更して、クロスコンパイルしたい

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, kernel

## 今の現状

libbpfを使ったコードを、x86環境で開発していました。　
最終的にはraspberry piで動かしたいので、`CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y`を有効にしたカーネルが必要になってきます。

## やったこと  (rasperry pi os)

[Building the Kernel Locally | raspberry pi document](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html#building)
[Build kernel with /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux enabled](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=349411)

を参考にして、カーネルをローカルでコンパイルしました。

```
cd linux
KERNEL=kernel8
make bcm2711_defconfig
```

を実行後、作成された.configを以下のように変更しました。

```
#
# Compile-time checks and compiler options
#
CONFIG_AS_HAS_NON_CONST_LEB128=y

CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_NONE=y -> CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_NONE=n　に変更
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=yを追加

# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF_TOOLCHAIN_DEFAULT is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF4 is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF5 is not set
CONFIG_FRAME_WARN=2048
# CONFIG_STRIP_ASM_SYMS is not set
# CONFIG_READABLE_ASM is not set
# CONFIG_HEADERS_INSTALL is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH is not set
CONFIG_SECTION_MISMATCH_WARN_ONLY=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_FORCE_FUNCTION_ALIGN_64B is not set
CONFIG_ARCH_WANT_FRAME_POINTERS=y
CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=y
CONFIG_VMLINUX_MAP=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_FORCE_WEAK_PER_CPU is not set
# end of Compile-time checks and compiler options
```

その後、

```
make -j4 Image.gz modules dtbs
sudo make modules_install
sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/broadcom/*.dtb /boot/firmware/
sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* /boot/firmware/overlays/
sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/README /boot/firmware/overlays/
sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/Image.gz /boot/firmware/$KERNEL.img
```

を実行し、カーネルの再構築を行いました。　
バージョンはきちんと、変わっていたのでコンパイル自体は成功しています。

しかし、再起動した後に変更したはずの.configが元に戻っていました。

## やったこと (ubuntu)

[ubuntu for rsapberry pi](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)

ラズパイ用のubuntuを[ラズパイ　クロスコンパイル](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html#cross-compiling-the-kernel)　を参考にクロスコンパイルを行おうと思いました。

しかし、こちらの方法では、SDカードをマウントしたところまではドキュメント通りうまくいきましたが、

```
sudo cp mnt/fat32/$KERNEL.img mnt/fat32/$KERNEL-backup.img
sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/Image mnt/fat32/$KERNEL.img
sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/broadcom/*.dtb mnt/fat32/
sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* mnt/fat32/overlays/
sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/README mnt/fat32/overlays/
sudo umount mnt/fat32
sudo umount mnt/ext4
```

クロスコンパイルしたものを、raspberry piに入れようとすると、
`mnt/fat32/$KERNEL.imgがない`といわれてしまい、どうすることもできません。

## 困っていること。

どうやっても、`CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF`を有効にしたカーネルをコンパイルすることができません。

[BTFを使うことができるosのバージョン](https://github.com/aquasecurity/btfhub/blob/main/docs/supported-distros.md)によると、ubuntuの22.4はBTFを有効にできそうです。

Ubuntu for Raspberry pi をクロスコンパイルする方法をご教授いただけたら、幸いです。

## 環境

cat version
Linux version 6.1.68-v8+ (lapis@Raspberrypi) (gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.40) #2 SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 19 19:38:41 JST 2023

Comment: 「mnt/fat32/$KERNEL.imgがない と言われてしまい」は、RasPi がインストールされた microSD をコンパイルしているマシン (Ubuntu) で事前にマウントしておく必要があるはずです。(手順をよく確認してください)

Comment: @cubick きちんとマウントしています。　説明不足でした。申し訳ないです。

Comment: マウントできているなら `/mnt/fat32/` の下にはなにかファイルはありますか？また、参照している手順では相対パスで指定している点も注意が必要です。`mnt/fat32/` と指定したなら、コマンドを実行したディレクトリ配下に `mnt` がある前提になります。

Comment: 相対パスで実行しています。　パスはあっていると思われます。　mnt/fat32/のフォルダー内にはいくつかのファイルが存在しましたが、そもそも.imgという拡張子のファイル自体存在しませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 困っていること。
> どうやっても、CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTFを有効にしたカーネルをコンパイルすることができません。

kernel configurationの手順が可怪しいように思えます

(raspberrypi.com) [Building the Kernel](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html) にほとんどのことは記されているので 一通り目を通したほうがよいでしょう。([Configuring the Kernel](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html#configuring-the-kernel) とか)

あとは, カーネルを `/boot/firmware/kernel8.img` としてコピーしても (たぶん現状 `vmlinuz`で起動するよう設定されてるはずで) 動かないはず。(設定変更するかファイル名変更するかが必要)

---

(以下はクロスコンパイルではなく, ラズパイ Ubuntuでの操作)

カーネルコンフィギュレーション(kernel configuration)について

```bash
$ grep CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO ./.config
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_NONE is not set
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF_TOOLCHAIN_DEFAULT=y
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF4 is not set
# CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_DWARF5 is not set
(略)
```

Debug information について内容確認すると, どれか選択する必要がありそう(とりあえず 2番目選択)

```
        ┌────────────────────── Debug information ──────────────────────┐
        │  Use the arrow keys to navigate this window or press the      │
        │  hotkey of the item you wish to select followed by the <SPACE │
        │  BAR>. Press <?> for additional information about this        │
        │ ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ │
        │ │( ) Disable debug information                              │ │
        │ │(X) Rely on the toolchain's implicit default DWARF version │ │
        │ │( ) Generate DWARF Version 4 debuginfo                     │ │
        │ │( ) Generate DWARF Version 5 debuginfo                     │ │
        │ │                                                           │ │
        │ │                                                           │ │
        │ └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ │
        ├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
        │                    <Select>      < Help >                     │
        └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

ビルド後 `vmlinuz` としてコピーし再起動
(その確認)

```bash
$ zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF_MODULES=y
$ bpftool btf dump file /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux format c
WARNING: bpftool not found for kernel 6.1.68-v8

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-6.1.68-v8-MY_CUSTOM_KERNEL+
    linux-cloud-tools-6.1.68-v8-MY_CUSTOM_KERNEL+

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-MY_CUSTOM_KERNEL+
    linux-cloud-tools-MY_CUSTOM_KERNEL+
$ ls /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux
/sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux
```

Comment: きちんと生成することはできました！

Comment: 実際にはカーネルのバージョンと, `initrd.img`(`initramfs`) や Linux C Library (`libc`) との整合性が取れていないとトラブルが発生するはずです。(基本的なことなので記されていないことも多いかもだけど, 知っておいたほうがよいかも)

Comment: ありがとうございます。

実際にlibbpfをコンパイルして、ロードするとできませんでした。 vmlinuzとしてコピーするのではなく、きちんと何かの設定ファイルを書き換えないとダメなんでしょうか？