# ラズパイでlibbpfを動かしたい (libbpf: failed to find valid kernel BTF)

Tags: linux, kernel, compiler

## やったこと

[raspberry piのBTFを有効にする方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98119/ubuntu-for-raspberry-pi%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)を参考にして、raspberry piの中のBTFを有効にすることに成功しました。

```
ls /sys/kernel/
btf     debug         irq    oops_count     rcu_normal  slab            tracing        warn_count
cgroup  fscaps        mm     profiling      reboot      software_nodes  uevent_helper
config  iommu_groups  notes  rcu_expedited  security    sunrpc          uevent_seqnum
```

その後、[libbpfのcoreバイナリ作成](https://gihyo.jp/admin/serial/01/ubuntu-recipe/0694)を参考に、コードを書いてx86のマシンでは動くコードを作成しました。

arm上でも動かしたいため、raspberry piでも動かしたいため同じようにコンパイルしました。
コンパイルも無事に成功しています。

```
make
clang -g -O2 -Wall -target bpf -D__TARGET_ARCH_arm64 -c hoge.bpf.c -o hoge.bpf.o
llvm-strip -g hoge.bpf.o
bpftool gen skeleton hoge.bpf.o > hoge.skel.h
cc -g -O2 -Wall -c hoge.c -o hoge.o
cc -g -O2 -Wall hoge.o -lbpf -o hoge

$ cat Makefile
#!/usr/bin/make -f

APPS = pre

CFLAGS += -g -O2 -Wall
LDFLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --libs libbpf)

ARCH ?= $(shell uname -m)
ARCH := $(patsubst x86_64,x86,$(ARCH))
ARCH := $(patsubst aarch64,arm64,$(ARCH))
ARCH := $(patsubst riscv64,riscv,$(ARCH))

.PHONY: all
all: $(APPS)

$(APPS): %: %.o %.skel.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

%.o: %.c %.skel.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.skel.h: %.bpf.o
        bpftool gen skeleton $< > $@

%.bpf.o: %.bpf.c vmlinux.h
        clang $(CFLAGS) -target bpf -D__TARGET_ARCH_$(ARCH) -c $< -o $@
        llvm-strip -g $@

vmlinux.h:
        bpftool btf dump file /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux format c > $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        -rm -f *.o *.skel.h vmlinux.h $(APPS)

.SECONDARY:
```

しかし、実行しようとすると、使えるBTFがないといわれます。

```
 sudo ./hoge
libbpf: failed to find valid kernel BTF
libbpf: Error loading vmlinux BTF: -3
libbpf: failed to load object 'hoge_bpf'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'hoge_bpf': -3
failed to load BPF object
```

## しりたいこと

どうすれば、動かせるようになるのでしょうか？
正直調べても解決策は見つけ出せませんでした。

## 環境

```
$ uname -a
Linux Raspberrypi 6.1.69-v8+ #2 SMP PREEMPT Sun Dec 24 19:29:08 JST 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux


$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

zgrep -E "(BPF|BTF)" /proc/config.gz
CONFIG_BPF=y
CONFIG_HAVE_EBPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_ARCH_WANT_DEFAULT_BPF_JIT=y
# BPF subsystem
CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT_ALWAYS_ON=y
CONFIG_BPF_JIT_DEFAULT_ON=y
CONFIG_BPF_UNPRIV_DEFAULT_OFF=y
# CONFIG_BPF_PRELOAD is not set
CONFIG_BPF_LSM=y
# end of BPF subsystem
CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_BPF=m
# CONFIG_BPFILTER is not set
CONFIG_NET_CLS_BPF=y
# CONFIG_NET_ACT_BPF is not set
# CONFIG_BPF_STREAM_PARSER is not set
CONFIG_LWTUNNEL_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF_LIRC_MODE2=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_SONY_BTF_MPX=m
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y
CONFIG_PAHOLE_HAS_SPLIT_BTF=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULE_ALLOW_BTF_MISMATCH=y
CONFIG_BPF_EVENTS=y
# CONFIG_TEST_BPF is not set

$ bpftool -V
bpftool v7.3.0
using libbpf v1.3
features: llvm, skeletons
```

### update

libbpf-tool内で、Makefileを自分が書いたコードもコンパイルするように変更して実行すると、うまくいきそうです。

[raspberry piのBTFを有効にする方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/98119/ubuntu-for-raspberry-pi%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)でできない理由がわかりませんが、実行できそうなので頑張ります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

手元の RasPi4 (Ubuntu)では, eBPF有効化している Kernelでは以下

```bash
$ sudo ./bootstrap
TIME     EVENT COMM             PID     PPID    FILENAME/EXIT CODE
^C
```

通常のカーネルで起動すると以下のように出ます

```bash
libbpf: failed to find valid kernel BTF
libbpf: Error loading vmlinux BTF: -3
libbpf: failed to load object 'bootstrap_bpf'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'bootstrap_bpf': -3
Failed to load and verify BPF skeleton
```

したがって Linuxカーネルが通常版と思われます

---

**Update**

検証を行ったアプリのビルド手順
[libbpf-bootstrap: demo BPF applications](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf-bootstrap) より

- [Building](https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf-bootstrap#building)

```bash
$ sudo apt install clang libelf1 libelf-dev zlib1g-dev
$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf-bootstrap
$ cd libbpf-bootstrap
```

`bootstrap` アプリの場合 (別箇所で Python起動＆終了)

```bash
$ cd examples/c
$ make
$ sudo ./bootstrap
TIME     EVENT COMM             PID     PPID    FILENAME/EXIT CODE
20:46:19 EXEC  python           1709    1583    /usr/bin/python
20:46:25 EXIT  python           1709    1583    [0] (5153ms)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。 uname -aで見ても、zgrep -E "(BPF|BTF)" /proc/config.gzで見ても、configを書き換えたカーネルのように見えます。　何がダメなのでしょうか？

Comment: configを書き換えて、コンパイルしたものは、vmlinuz上にコピーして再起動させてる状態です。

Comment: 同じように検証を行うと、無事に起動できました。。。。

自作のコードの方は動かないので、むしろ謎が深まりました。。。。